# Set a new column with the other rows account_no when the 2 rows have same values in some columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to populate the `AccountKey` in the table.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
     sub_no        INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
     ,account_no   INTEGER NOT NULL
     ,rep          VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
     ,security_no  INTEGER NOT NULL
     ,symbol       VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL
     ,asofdate     DATE NOT NULL
     ,qty          INTEGER NOT NULL
     ,abs_qty      INTEGER NOT NULL
     ,CrossAccount BIT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO mytable (sub_no, account_no, rep, security_no, symbol, asofdate, qty, abs_qty, CrossAccount,) 
VALUES (177, 12345, 'X', 2000, 'A', '20180101', 100, 100, 1), 
       (177, 23456, 'Y', 2000, 'A', '20180101', -100, 100, 1),
       (177, 34567, 'Z', 5000, 'A', '20180101', 300, 300, 0),
       (177, 45455, 'Z', 5000, 'A', '20170909', 300, 300, 0),
       (160, 65432, 'A', 9999, 'B', '20180202', -500, 500, 1),
       (160, 54321, 'B', 9999, 'C', '20180202', 500, 500, 1);
```

The output table with the new column `AccountKey` is shown below.

```
sub_no account_no rep security_no symbol asofdate qty  abs_qty CrossAcct AccountKey

177    12345      X   2000        A      20180101 100  100     1         177-23456
177    23456      Y   2000        A      20180101 -100 100     1         177-12345
177    34567      Z   5000        A      20180101 300  300     0         NULL
177    45455      Z   5000        A      20170909 300  300     0         NULL
160    65432      A   9999        B      20180202 -500 500     1         160-54321
160    54321      B   9999        C      20180202 500  500     1         160-65432
```

When the security_no, asofdate and abs_qty are same then the CrossAcct value is populated as 1.

When the CrossAcct value is 1, the two accounts that have same security_no, asofdate and abs_qty, each should have AccountKey = sub_no+'-'+account_no of the other account.

In the above table, entries 1 and 2 have same security_no, asofdate and abs_qty. So for the first entry, the AccountKey = 177-23456 which is the sub_no and account_no of the 2nd entry in the pair.

So whenever the two rows have same security_no, asoddate, and abs_qty then the first row's AccountKey should be populated from the second row's sub_no and account_no and vice versa.

Comment: So you only can have the same `security_no`  1 or 2 times? not 3 or more?

Comment: The combination of same (security_no, asofdate and abs_qty) will always in the pair. One where qty is positive and other where qty is negative.

Comment: So you can have same security pair but different qty? You should show that in your data

Comment: ABS(qty) will always be same for the pair. One record will have positive value, other will have negative value. As shown in the data, when security_no, asofdate and abs_qty is same between 2 records, one will have positive qty lets say X and the other will have negative qty = -X.

Comment: I ask again, can the same security_no appear more than 2 times in the table?

Comment: Yes. Security_no can appear more than 2 times.

Comment: then you need specify how do the match.

Comment: In another words, If Person A buys 100 stocks of IBM(security_no) from Person B, Then A is +100, B is -100. So the AccountKey of A shoud be B, and AccountKey of B should be A. There can also be person C and D, who are buying and selling IBM.

Comment: when security_no, asofdate and abs_qty  columns are same, that is when they form a pair.

Comment: How you difference A-B from C-D if both operation are the same day from same ammount?

Comment: That's a good question. The security_no is setup in such a way that it does not repeat for the sameday. So we can not have A-b and C-D for the same security_no, on the same day.

Comment: So to answer your question more clearly, when the combination of security_no, asofdate and abs_qty are same, they will always be 2 such rows. not more, not less.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: What's wrong with something like `select t1.*, AccountKey = cast(t2.sub_no as varchar(255)) + '-' + cast(t2.account_no as varchar(255)) from mytable as t1 left join mytable as t2 on t1.sub_no = t2.sub_no and t1.security_no = t2.security_no and t1.asofdate = t2.asofdate and t1.account_no != t2.account_no and t1.crossacct = 1 and t2.crossacct = 1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple ways of getting the desired results based on your sample data.

One way is to use a left self join...

```
SELECT 
    mt1.*,
    AccountKey = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), mt1.sub_no) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), mt2.account_no)
FROM
    #mytable mt1
    LEFT JOIN #mytable mt2
        ON mt1.sub_no = mt2.sub_no
        AND mt1.security_no = mt2.security_no
        AND mt1.asofdate = mt2.asofdate
        AND mt1.abs_qty = mt2.abs_qty
        AND mt1.qty + mt2.qty = 0;
```

Another option would be to use the LEAD & LAG functions...

```
SELECT 
    mt.*,
    AccountKey = ISNULL(LEAD(CONCAT(mt.sub_no, '-', mt.account_no), 1) OVER (PARTITION BY mt.sub_no, mt.security_no, mt.asofdate, mt.abs_qty ORDER BY mt.qty),
    LAG(CONCAT(mt.sub_no, '-', mt.account_no), 1) OVER (PARTITION BY mt.sub_no, mt.security_no, mt.asofdate, mt.abs_qty ORDER BY mt.qty))
FROM
    #mytable mt;
```

Comment: Jason, I was able to workout the output using your LEAD & LAG solution. Thank you for your valuable time.